# Time complexity and space of the function

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science

im sturggling with finding complexity of the next function

```
void what(int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int x = n;
        while (x > 0)
            x -= i;
    }
}
```

ive tried to solve it by the next things
at looking on space i found its only O(1) since no taking of it.
when thinking of time
i thought that since its each time being devided it will be n(1+1/2 +1/4+....)=O(N.log(N))
is it correct?
thank you

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre not sure what you mean by O(2), is that a type-O?

Answer (score 1):

A simplistic analysis gives a time complexity of **O(N.log(N))**, but it should be noted that the loop does not compute anything: local variable `x` is decremented `n / i` times and discarded.  A good compiler should be able to compile the whole function to a no-op: `void what(int n) {}`, which a resulting complexity of **O(1)**, both for space and time.